# Dapper INSERT/UPDATE CamelCase to Snake_Case for 70+ properties model

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, dapper

Problem is, SQL has stored procedure with snake_case columns and on c# side I have model with ~70+ columns and CamelCase properties names.

```
  public void EditProfileSettings(ProfileSettingsEdit profileSettings)
    {
        using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = InitializeSqlConnection(_config.DataExportApplication))
        {
            DefaultTypeMap.MatchNamesWithUnderscores = true;

            sqlConnection.Query<ProfileSettingsEdit>(
               "usp_profilesettings_update",
               profileSettings,
               commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
        }
    }
```

I know this might be a duplicate, but nothing similar I found worked for me..
I believe custom mapper could solve this, but is it possible to solve  this without writing rule for every property. ?

Quick solution:

Well, for now I can live with this:

```
public void EditProfileSettings(ProfileSettingsEdit profileSettings)
    {
        using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = InitializeSqlConnection(_config.DataExportApplication))
        {
            var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
            var props = profileSettings.GetType().GetProperties();

            for (int i = 0; i < props.Length; i++)
            {
                parameters.Add(props[i].Name.ToUnderscoreCase(), props[i].GetValue(profileSettings));
            }

            sqlConnection.Query<ProfileSettingsEdit>(
               "usp_profilesettings_update",
               parameters,
               commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
        }
    }

 public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static string ToUnderscoreCase(this string str)
    {
        return string.Concat(str.Select((x, i) => i > 0 && char.IsUpper(x) ? "_" + x.ToString() : x.ToString())).ToLower();
    }
}
```

Not sure how performance hungry it's going to be.. but if someone can come up with something better, please, feel free to help me out

Comment: What is the problem? SQL object names aren't case sensitive.

Comment: You didn't explain what the problem is if any, or post the *relevant* code - the stored procedure definition and the class.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
var map = new CustomPropertyTypeMap(typeof(ProfileSettingsEdit), 
    (type, columName) => new Func<Type, string, propertyInfo>(
        {
            return type.GetProperty(columnName).ToUnderscoreCase();
        }
    ));
```

And then

```
SqlMapper.SetTypeMap(typeof(ProfileSettingsEdit), map);
```

I suspect that setting the type map once is more performant than running the code every time you execute.

This is typed off of the top of my head, so beware of syntax errors.